# Using the general binomial theorem to find a series-like expression for $\sqrt 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, binomial-coefficients, power-series

How do I use the general binomial theorem (i.e. the series expansion of ${(1+x)^\alpha}$ for $ |x|<1$) to show the following? $$\sqrt 2=1+\frac 1{2^2}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2!\cdot{2^4}} +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot4}{3!\cdot{2^6}}+\cdots+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{n!\cdot{2^{2n}}} +\cdots $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $\frac12\sqrt 2 = (1-\frac12)^{1/2}$

Comment: Ohh ok, makes sense! But the given hint (which I had neglected to state in my question above) was to use $(1+x)^{-1/2}$. Do you think this was a typo?? Thanks!

Comment: Also fine with, $(1-\frac12)^{-1/2}=\sqrt 2$ as well.. Maybe even better as I did not really compute the coefficients. With my hint you get summands with alternating signs that can hopefully be combined nicely. The original hint makes this unnecessary and should giv ethe summands directly. Try it.

Comment: Thank you, your second suggestion works.